# How to Join table in adventure works (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server

```
insert into DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01.[dbo].[DimProducts] 
(
[ProductID],
[ProductName],
[ProductColor],
[ProductListPrice],
[ProductSize],
[ProductWeight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductCategoryName] 
)
select P1.ProductID, 
       P1.Name, 
       P1.Color, 
       P1.ListPrice, 
       P1.Size, 
       P1.Weight, 
       P2.ProductCategoryID, 
       P2.Name from [AdventureWorksLT2012].[SalesLT].[Product] P1 
JOIN   [AdventureWorksLT2012].[SalesLT].[ProductCategory] P2 
on     P1.ProductCategoryID = P2.ProductCategoryID 
where  ProductID IS NOT NULL
```

and I got this:

> "Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 206
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProductColor', table 'DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01.dbo.DimProducts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated."

can solve that?

Comment: This is confusing. Why do you think the issue has anything to do with a join?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid nulls in you select sentence by using [COALESCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) or [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) functions.

**COALESCE(** *expression [ ,...n ]* **)**

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL. For example, SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value'); returns the third value because the third value is the first value that is not null.

**ISNULL(** *check_expression , replacement_value* **)**

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

```
INSERT INTO DWAdventureWorksLT2012Lab01.[dbo].[DimProducts] 
(
[ProductID],
[ProductName],
[ProductColor],
[ProductListPrice],
[ProductSize],
[ProductWeight],
[ProductCategoryID],
[ProductCategoryName] 
)
SELECT P1.ProductID, 
       P1.Name, 
       COALESCE(P1.Color, 0), -- or '' if it is a char column
       P1.ListPrice, 
       ISNULL(P1.Size, 0), 
       P1.Weight, 
       P2.ProductCategoryID, 
       P2.Name from [AdventureWorksLT2012].[SalesLT].[Product] P1 
JOIN   [AdventureWorksLT2012].[SalesLT].[ProductCategory] P2 
ON     P1.ProductCategoryID = P2.ProductCategoryID 
WHERE  ProductID IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The column *ProductColor* is NON-NULLABLE. You can see that in the DDL.

- Click on the table and expand it with the plus sign +
- Then expand the column folder. You'll see the column definition.

This means you need to make sure there is a color for each product--or if you want to change the design, make the column *NULL*. I'm not a fan of using place holder values like 0 or blank spaces. This the perfect case for *NULL*